# Do I need to include a default Intent in order to return to the previous Activity?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a To Do List Android application (it happens to be for a class assignment, but that's not what I'm asking about--I've tried to leave out as much code as I could). The main screen displays a list of ToDo items with a button at the bottom to open the Add New ToDo Item screen.

[image: Initial ToDo List view]

On the Add New ToDo Item screen, there is a Cancel button.

[image: Add New ToDo Item view]

Relevant ToDoManagerActivity.java snippet:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Init and setup adapter, etc.

        footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ToDoManagerActivity.this, AddToDoActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        // Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    log("Entered onActivityResult()");

    // Check result code and request code.
    // If user submitted a new ToDoItem
    // Create a new ToDoItem from the data Intent
    // and then add it to the adapter
}
```

Relevant AddToDoActivity.java snippet:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Initialize default view, handle other events, etc.

    final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

The above code works. Previously, I was trying this in the `onClick` handler for `cancelButton`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    finishActivity(RESULT_CANCELED);
}
```

When I clicked the Cancel button, I could see that the `onActivityResult` was being reached in the logs, but the screen was not reverting back to the main ToDo list screen.

Why does the above code not return me to the previous screen, but the following code does return me to the previous screen? What am I misunderstanding about the task backstack/activities?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
    finish();
}
```

Comment: In both cases you're calling `finish()` after setting the result?

Comment: I am calling `finish` in one and `finishActivity` in the other. I edited the question to clarify what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29):

> public void finish ()
>
> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
>   onActivityResult().

and

> public void finishActivity (int requestCode)
>
> Force finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(Intent, int).

You should call `finish()` to close the current activity and `finishActivity()` to close another activity you started using `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`. Calling `finishActivity()` on the current activity will not close it.

Also, there's no point in creating a new `Intent` for `setResult()` as you are not passing back any data. Doing this would be sufficient:

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

From Android Docs:

> public void finishActivity (int requestCode) 
>   Force finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(Intent, int).

finishActivity does not finish the current activity but calls finish for an activity called with requestCode

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity%28int%29) for `finishActivity()` it says that it will force finish an activity started with `startActivityForResult()`, but you have to pass in the request code that you used to start the other activity. In your case it would be `ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST`.

This is probably not the API you want to use. Your 2nd method is cleaner in that you don't need to force close the child activity, but let it finish in the normal way.